# Request that does absolutely nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to make a button which triggers a request to render a login page. I want to limit the login page to only the admins of my project. I have their ip addresses and use those to check against those from the database. If the ip matches, I want the login page to be rendered, but if it doesen't match, then I want the page to be as it is. I don't want page reload or page redirection. I want it like the button is not working at all. The page should not be trying to fetch a response.

I want something like this -

I have a button which is a submit form, it contains the ip of the user.

```
app.post("/something",function(req,res){
  Admins.findOne({userIP:req.body.userIP},function(err,foundItem){
     if(!err){
       if(foundItem){
         res.render("login");
       }else{

       }
  });
});
```

I am not sure what code needs to go in the `else` section. `res.end()` is not working for me as a blank white page is shown if I use that. I want the page to be as it is and where it is.

Please help guys! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like an unusual approach.  Typically, you would present the login page to _all_ users, and then perhaps only admins with certain credentials would be allowed to login.  Why do you want to go the route of using an IP whitelist/blacklist as you have done here?

Comment: If you know the IP in the first place, then its good to block any from loading at all to other users. This can be implemented at many levels. Easiest approach is to configure your web server(apache/nginx/others) to allow from only certain IP's

Comment: @Tim I have a GUI for the management of database. The login page rendered to all users would be useless as they have nothing to do with it. Also security issues pour in if the page is open to all.

Answer (score 1):

First this is not node js problem. This is normal Form submit and basic html stuff.
Second When you click on submit button automatically refreshes the `client` page and wait for new rendered page from `server`.

So basically what you need to do is render the same page where you have implemented the Form with action attribute.

(or)

You have to add onsubmit attribute in Form tag with a javascript function where you need to call an node js api and in node js you need to `res.send({status:true (or) false})` which when you get in `response` from api call you conditionally stay or go to login page.